# Example function in haskell needed - function :: Num b => b -> a -> [a]

Tags: haskell

Could someone please give me a example of a function that would use this data type:

```
function :: Num b => b -> a -> [a]
function a b = ...
```

Also ideally a would be a string.

No this is not homework xD I just need an example for a project.

I have tried take b (repeat a) but I get the error

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
from the context (Num b)
```

Comment: This signature doesn't make much sense for the task you'd like it to fulfill. What is `function 7.3 "foo"` supposed to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work (it's a function that fits the type description):

```
function :: Num b => b -> a -> [a]
function arg1 arg2 = [arg2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could repeat the given element (of type `a`) `b` times to create the list

Comment: I have tried take b (repeat a) but I get the error Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
    from the context (Num b)

Comment: `take` takes an `Int`, so you would have to explicitly convert the `Num` to `Int`.  On second thought, `Num` could be a floating point number as well, so at that point you need to re-think what repeating something b times means (e.g. round it first)

Answer (score 1):

The Prelude provides a number of functions (like `take`, `drop`, `!!`, `splitAt`, and so forth) that are needlessly monomorphic: they require that the number they're given is an `Int`. The module `Data.List` exports more polymorphic versions of these functions which take an argument of any type in the `Integral` class; they have the same name, but are prefixed by `generic`. So, instead of `take a (repeat b)`, you may try

```
function a b = genericTake a (repeat b)
```

Comment: The `generic...` functions take any type of the `Integral` class, which makes much more sense than `Num`.